# How do I get my while loop to return to the beginning of the function?

Tags: python

I am making a choice-based game in repl.it, and am allowing the player to choose the color of their turtle. Ideally my function asks them for a color, and checks to see if its correct. if the color they pick doesn't match, it gives an error message and is supposed to return to the beginning of the function to ask them again. It works when I put in the wrong color, but when I put in a valid answer I am stuck on a never-ending loop of "invalid color selection". I've tried using only if statements, returns, and landed upon the while loop and I have been trying to get it to work. I am new to coding. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
def rajColorPick():
  NotSelected = True;
  rajColor = str(input("What color would you like raj to be?"));
  colors = ["purple", "pink", "red", "blue", "green"];
  while NotSelected == True:
    if rajColor == colors:
      NotSelected = False;
      tortuga.color(rajColor); 
    elif rajColor != colors:
      print("Invalid color selection. Try again");
      rajColorPick();
  


rajColorPick();
```

Comment: Take out the `rajColorPick();` that is inside the function. You do not need a recursive call in addition to your explicit loop. Also you don't need all the semicolons.

Comment: The ``==`` operator checks **equality**, it does not check if something is part of something else.

Comment: Side note: get rid of all those semicolons. They are totally superflous in Python, unless you want to write everything in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `in` operator to see if the user input is in the list of colors, and `return` once you have valid input:

```
def rajColorPick():
    while True:
        rajColor = str(input("What color would you like raj to be?"))
        if rajColor in ["purple", "pink", "red", "blue", "green"]:
            tortuga.color(rajColor)
            return
        print("Invalid color selection. Try again")


rajColorPick()
```